# SQL Column Name cannot be indexed by jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

I am trying to read data from `MySql` with `PHP` and then send results with `json_encode` to client. I am then using `jQuery` script to read the results but unable to index the columns in the `JSON` because of the type of name given to the column has brackets in it `COUNT(ID)`.

I am trying to learn several things at once, `jQuery`, `SQL` etc and think there must be a better/easier way?

I have made a `SQL` query to **count** the number of times a name appears in one of the columns. It returns a column name `COUNT(ID)`...

SQL query:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID), LocationName FROM myDB GROUP BY LocationName'
```

`jQuery` reading the `JSON` into arrays:

```
for(var i in data)
{
    getProfileName.push = data[i].ProfileName;
    getLocationCount.push = data[i].COUNT(ID)
}
```

I receive the `JSON` in my `jQuery` script, and it has the 2 columns `LocationName` and `COUNT(ID)`

But obviously I cannot use the index name of `COUNT(ID)` because of the brackets.

How do you reference names with brackets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give an ***alias*** for `COUNT(ID)` in your query, something like below:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) as totalIdCount, LocationName FROM myDB GROUP BY LocationName
//------------------^you can chang alias name according to your comfort --------//
```

Now use this alias in jQuery

```
for(var i in data)
{
    getProfileName.push = data[i].ProfileName;
    getLocationCount.push = data[i].totalIdCount
}
```

Note:- you can try `data[i]['COUNT(ID)']` directly in your jQuery code, but above is the standard practice.

Comment: _"need"_ is a strong word. OP _could_ use `data[i]['COUNT(ID)']`

Comment: Thanks 0- exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @Phil  agreed, but it's better to do things in more appropriate way (or we can say standard way)

Comment: Oh, I totally agree. This is **much** better